# How to I return a null value to to a database using c#

Tags: c#

I have created a function that should send a null value back to my database if the field length of the string is less than 2 characters but instead, it changes it to 00-00-00 on the database. Can someone please point me in the right direction.

```
public string dateChanger(string txtBox)     
     if (txtBox.Length < 2)
            {
                return DBNull.Value.ToString();

            }
            else
            {
                var date = txtBox;

                var name = date.Substring(6, 4) + "-" + date.Substring(3, 2) + "-" + date.Substring(0, 2);
                return name;
            }
}
```

Below is the code I used to call function "dateChanger" and insert into database

```
     [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult AjaxMethodSaveStudent(string cboStudentName = "", string cboStudentSurname = "", string txtStudentMiddleName = "", string txtStudentNumber = "", string txtStudentDOB = "", string txtStudentPreferredName = "", string txtStudentPropertyName = "", string txtStudentRegImmiCardNumber = "")
        {
            long studentId = 0;
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
            {
                string queryStudent = "INSERT INTO `STUDENT REGISTER` " +
                    "(`first name`, " +
                    "`surname`, " +
                    "`Middle Names`," +
                    "`DATE OF BIRTH`," +
                    "`ImmiCardNumber`) " +
                    "VALUES" +
                    "('" + cboStudentName + "'," +
"'" + cboStudentSurname + "'," +
"'" + txtStudentMiddleName + "'," +
"'" + dateChanger(txtStudentDOB) + "'," +
"'" + txtStudentRegImmiCardNumber + "') ";
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryStudent))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    studentId = cmd.LastInsertedId;

                    con.Close();
                }
            }

            return Json(new { success = true, studentId = studentId }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: How do you actually insert those values? You should be using Paramtized queries. Not only are they immune to SQL Injections, they can also inform you off issues. In this case it is less then clear what thoes values repesent. Some kind of String Encoded date? If so, how and when are you parsing it into the proper types?

Comment: I have updated the code to show how I pass the information to the database.

Comment: Building quers via string conaction is just a bad idea all around. Parametised Querries give you immunity to SQL Injections, Type Safety, as well as a execution speed advantage. You should not be using strings unless it is for user facing I/O. Parse whatever string you got into a proper fitting type (int, float, DateTime) ASAP. Also is the Column in the DB actually marked as "allows null value"?

Comment: Need to emphasize parameterized queries again. The code as written is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks. They will also remove any need to use or maintain the `dateChanger()` function, which makes to whole question irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naive solution to the problem is to change the function like this:

```
public string dateChanger(string txtBox)     
{    
    if (txtBox.Length < 2) return "NULL";

    return txtBox.Substring(6, 4) + "-" + txtBox.Substring(3, 2) + "-" + txtBox.Substring(0, 2);
}
```

A slightly improved version of the function looks like this:

```
public string dateChanger(string txtBox)     
{    
    if (txtBox.Length < 2) return "NULL";

    return "'" + DateTime.Parse(txtBox).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'";
}
```

Note both of these require moving the responsibility for the SQL single quotes to the function. Otherwise there is nothing you could possibly return from this function that would ever put a `NULL` value into the database, because the database would treat it as a string literal. Rather than `+ "'" + dateChanger(...) + "'" +` you just want `+ dateChanger(...) +`. You also need to think about how to handle the need for `IS` rather than `=` when comparing to `NULL`.

**But don't do either of these!**

Both those possibilities pander to the poor practice of providing parameter data as strings. This has negative consequences for performance, maintainability, and security. *Just don't do it.*

The best option removes the `dateChanger()` function from the project completely, in favor of something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AjaxMethodSaveStudent(string cboStudentName = "", string cboStudentSurname = "", string txtStudentMiddleName = "", string txtStudentNumber = "", string txtStudentDOB = "", string txtStudentPreferredName = "", string txtStudentPropertyName = "", string txtStudentRegImmiCardNumber = "")
{
    long studentId = 0;
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
    string queryStudent = 
       "INSERT INTO `STUDENT REGISTER` " +
             "(`first name`, `surname`, `Middle Names`,`DATE OF BIRTH`, `ImmiCardNumber`) " +
       "VALUES (@StudentName, @Surname, @MiddleName, @DOB, @ImmiCardNumber);";

    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryStudent, con))
    {
        //Use actual types and lengths from the database here.
        // Do NOT use AddWithValue() to skip setting parameter types.
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@StudentName", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = cboStudentName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Surname", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = cboStudentSurname;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@MiddleName", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = txtStudentMiddleName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DOB", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value =  (txtStudentDOB.Length > 2) ? DateTime.Parse(txtStudentDOB.Substring(6, 4) + "-" + txtStudentDOB.Substring(3, 2) + "-" + txtStudentDOB.Substring(0, 2)) : (object)DBNull.Value;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ImmiCardNumber", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = txtStudentRegImmiCardNumber;

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        studentId = cmd.LastInsertedId;
    }

    return Json(new { success = true, studentId = studentId }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I will change it over and hopefully, it works. FYI the date changer function still didn't work with your changes but if it's a bad idea, I am just going to leave it alone and work with your improvements.